# How do I make the engine.say() work in my code?

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I found an offline speech recognizer and tried to integrate a pyttsx3 module so that the word that I speak is also spoken by the pyttsx3. Basically it is a speech to text to speech code, but the engine.say does not seem to work. What should I do?

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer

import pyaudio
import pyttsx3


model = Model(r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\SpeechRecog\vosk-model-tl-ph-generic-0.6")
recognizer = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)

engine = pyttsx3.init()

mic = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = mic.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8192)
stream.start_stream()


while True:
    data = stream.read(4096)

    if recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
        word = recognizer.Result()
        engine.say(word)
        print(word)
        print(word[14:-3])
```

I tried to insert the code of a text to speech into my speech recognizer code

Answer (score 0):

You can view video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVboOz_O8rE. It working for win 10 and same with your requirements